# Debugging the Interwoven Worksite Web Services

Tags: .net, web-services, api, document-management

***EDIT:*** Web Services being called from a windows console application at present, using VB.Net and Visual Studio 2008

We are using the Interwoven Worksite Web Services and are having issues debugging them.  The web service is returning the following error:

> *"Unable to access the object. It may have been deleted or you may not have
>   security access."*

However there is no more detail than this coming through from the service.  I have read the official Interwoven documentation and found it to be remarkably unhelpful.

Does anyone have any real world experience with the Worksite web services (they specifically come with the Worksite Web product, not to be confused with their COM API, which we have used within web services).

I did a search on worksite and interwoven and didn't find anything on here so I'm not sure anyone out there will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - have used it and have had same issue. usually with that error you are not providing the full and/or correct moniker info, e.g. wrong dms name, wrong object id. I used fiddler to view the info being passed to/fro on the base worksite web product to see how they format those same IDs which helped alot. I hope this helps.